# Is it possible to disable Gmail conversation threading from a URL parameter?

Tags: gmail, gmail-conversations

I have a search that I use to quickly delete some regular messages that I receive from a monitoring system, but some of them I want to keep.

Because the subjects are all the same they all appear within the same conversation threads.

If I turn off threading temporarily, then the search results show just the messages I want to delete and then I can select-all and delete, leaving just the ones I need to devote special attention to.

I love the conversation threads and don't want to lose that permanently and find it a bore having to turn them off through the settings and then back on again afterwards.

What would be great is to either have a special tag that goes in the search or a different URL (like the basic HTML view) which would disable the conversation thread view just for that search.

Answer (score 1):

Not specifically the solution you were looking for, but you *can* delete individual messages from a threaded conversation. You just need to use the message menu rather than the global delete button.

[image: Gmail message menu]

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do here is: view and delete the messages using [Mobile version of GMail](http://m.gmail.com/%22Mobile%20Version%20of%20GMail%22)

It will also open in your Computer.